# click event for option doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a multiple select tag, and I need to write the function onclick of it's options, because I need to get the value of last clicked option, but when I wrote the following

```
$("#multiple_select option").click(function()
{
     var val = $(this).val();
     alert(val);
});
```

it doesn't work in IE.

What is the problem?

### UPDATE

I need exactly click event, because I wrote a function onclick event already(demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6TZrH/)), and I need to fix last changed element's value, which is impossible to make without click event(I think)

Comment: how about this? http://jsfiddle.net/6TZrH/1/

Comment: Thanks much man:/ very interestnig solution(i don't know about `.not` method)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

don't bind it on option

```
$("#multiple_select").click(function(){
     alert("works");
});
```

---

accepted answer:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var options = $("#supply_cities_select :selected");
    var lastOption;
    $("#supply_cities_select").click(function()
        {
            lastOption = $(this).find(':selected').not(options);
            options = $(this).find(':selected');
        })
});
```

Comment: i need to bind on option, becouse i need to get clicked option's value, look at update please

Comment: this would just fire each time you click on the `select` element, you need to use a `change event handler`

Comment: This would work fine. You just need to check if the element the was click was an option (e.target.tagName == "OPTION"). Google event delegation for more.

Comment: @edeverett: either I'm completley off or that is just wrong. Would you mind to post an example of what you mean?

Comment: @jAndy I'm wrong. Of course, if the click event isn't supported on the option elements, just moving the event binding won't help! However, in investigating this I've found an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to have a `click event` on each option, you need to have `List` instead of a `dropdown` style.

To accomplish that, add the `size` attribute into the `select` element for instance:

```
<select type="multiple" size=4>
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
  <option>baseball</option>
</select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Now you can bind each `option` individually.

If you want to get the value of a clicked option use the `change` event handler and `.val()` method, like:

```
$("#multiple_select").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  alert(val);
});
```

Comment: as I thought of it, the OP wanted to get the last clicked element option

Comment: Nice one with the "size" methodology :) +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#multiple_select").click(function(){
  alert($(this).children("option:selected").val());
});
```

should to the thing

Comment: My fault, I didn't get you could get several options.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="multiple_select" size="4">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#multiple_select').click(function() {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });

</script>
```

The alert window, depending on the choice you made, shows the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery focus() on option, rather than click().

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's some IE weirdness:

Using IE, in the click event function, `event.srcElement.value` gives the value of the last clicked option.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ch2DT/ (only tested in IE8, needs work to make it cross browser)

Answer (score 0):

I liked @Reigel's (accepted) answer but needed to improve it for use in one of my projects.  In the code below, I introduce a new function "findClickedOption" that accounts for the fact that maybe a user will re-click an already-selected option. This still doesn't account for CTRL-clicking multiple options but is good enough for me.

```
    var multiselect_s=$('#ms2side__sx');
    var options_s =multiselect_s.find('option:selected');
    multiselect_s.live('click',function(){
      var clickedOption =findClickedOption($(this), options_s);
      options_s = $(this).find('option:selected');
      doSomething(clickedOption);//call your own function here
    });

    function findClickedOption(selectbox, optionsArr){
      var selectedOptions=selectbox.find('option:selected');
      if(selectedOptions.size>1){
        return selectedOptions.not(optionsArr);        
      }else{
        return selectedOptions;
      }
    }
```