# Get clicked option in multiple dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a multi select dropdown eg:

```
<select id="myList" multiple="multiple">  
    <option value="1">Opt #1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Opt #2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">Opt #3</option>
    <option value="4">Opt #4</option>
</select>
```

If I then selects `Opt #4`, how do I then only get `Opt #4` and not `Opt #2` and `Opt #3`? I know I can get all selected options by this:

```
var selectedOptions = $("#myList option:selected");
```

However I only want the option I clicked - `Opt #4`. Is this possible?

Edit: note that as I manipulate the list inside a `change` event I can't do it in a `click` event. Also added missing multiple.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you want to get the "clicked" option, why is a multi select?

Comment: Did you miss to add `multiple` attribute to select tag?

Comment: You've missed the `mulitple="multiple"` attribute off your `select`. Other than that it should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get it in the click handler for each option element:

```
$("#myList option").click(function() {
    var clickedOption = $(this);
});
```

---

**Update**

> EDIT: As I manipulate the list inside a change event, I can't do it in a click event.

In that case you need to delegate the event using `on`. Try this:

```
$("#myList").on("click", "option", function() {
    var clickedOption = $(this);
});
```

One thing to note, however, is that `option` elements will not raise `click` events at all in IE, so neither of the above will not work in that browser.

Comment: This will add a single event handler to each option. If you ever added options after calling this, the new options will not work as expected. Please look at my solution on how to avoid this problem.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I manipulate the list inside a change event, so I can't do it in a click event.

Comment: Note that for multiple select, you can unchecked options, so you may need to check if the option is selected or not with $(this).is(':selected').

Comment: I know this is old, but people who are looking for a general solution should be warned that this doesn't work in any version of Internet Explorer as far as I can see, including 11.  Mouse events aren't raised from HTML option elements in IE.

Comment: @RichN That has been the case for a [long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341740/click-event-for-option-doesnt-work-in-ie). I'll add a note about it in this answer though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, If the user clicked on opt #4 without Cntrl key pressed, then you will only get Opt#4 as the selected option.

If the user clicked on opt #4 with Cntrl key pressed, then all three options will be selected. So all three options will be returned. If you want only Opt#4, then you would need to add a click event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like the following help you?

```
$('#myList').delegate('option', 'click', function (opt) {
  alert('Option ' + opt.value + ' was clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The real answer:

```js
select.onclick = function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
};
```