# How to get CLICKED option from a select[multiple] in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I need the option element the user clicked on in a multiple select control in Internet Explorer. StackOverflow helpfully suggested these questions:

[Get clicked option in multiple dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431381/jquery-get-clicked-option-in-multiple-dropdown)

[How to get clicked option value of a multiple select, fired by .change() event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525114/how-to-get-clicked-option-value-of-a-multiple-select-fired-by-change-event)

but neither one works in Internet Exploder.

example 1:
https://jsfiddle.net/c8q956dr/

```
  $("body").on("click", "select[multiple]",
               function(e)
               {
                   log("click: "+ e.target.value);  
               });
```

this one works by attaching the click event to the select element, and works perfectly in Chrome/Firefox, as they return the option the user clicked in the event.target member. IE, on the other hand, returns the entire select element and offers no indication which option was clicked.

example 2:
https://jsfiddle.net/55up15Lb/1/

```
  $("select option").click(  
               function(e)
               {
                   log("click: "+ this.value);  
               });
```

this one works by attaching the click event handler directly to the option elements, but I cannot get it to work at all in IE.

I've tried IE 8, 9, and 11. am I stuck?

Comment: Options don't reliably fire mouse events, you should be getting the selects value instead, or at least just the selected options, there shouldn't be a need for getting the clicked option.

Comment: I need to select other list items when certain other list items are selected.

Comment: yes, sorry, should have mentioned I need Ctrl+Click to work.

Comment: In other browsers you can check if clicked option is selected by event.originalTarget.selected but I don't know how it can happens in IE also