# Limit the number of options a user can select in D3 dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm relatively new to D3 and have been having a few issues getting started. I've created a dropdown menu using the code below

```
var signal = d3.select('#signal_container');
var signalName = ["Please Select", "Temperature", "Pressure", "Load"];
var signalSelect = signal
    .append('select')
    .attr('class', 'select')
    .attr('multiple', '');
var signalOptions = signalSelect
    .selectAll('option')
    .data(signalName).enter()
    .append('option')
    .text(function (d) { return d; });
```

I was wondering if there was a way to limit the number of options that the user can select in the multiple select dropdown menu? Say I want to set the limit at 2 and they've selected 'Temperature' and 'Load', if they were to try and select 'Pressure' it wouldn't be possible as the limit for selected options is set at 2.

Also, how would I be able to get the values of the selected options? I'm currently using

```
d3.select('#signal_container').select('select').property('value');
```

But obviously that is only getting the value of the first select options.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Your first question (*limit the number of options that the user selects*) makes no sense. Can you clarify it?

Comment: I've edited the question. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Not really. I believe you want a checkbox, not a dropdown. I mean, you can do it using a dropdown, but it's not intuitive for the user.

Comment: Ok. I will try that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of way to do what you are after programmatically.  Here's one such implementation that handles the enable/disable of options in the click event of the options:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="signal_container"></div>
  <br/>
  <button id="someButton">Get Values!</button>
  <script>
    var signal = d3.select('#signal_container');
    var signalName = ["Please Select", "Temperature", "Pressure", "Load"];
    var signalSelect = signal
      .append('select')
      .attr('class', 'select')
      .attr('multiple', '');

    var selectedValues = [];
    var signalOptions = signalSelect
      .selectAll('option')
      .data(signalName).enter()
      .append('option')
      .text(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .on('click', function(d) {
        var s = signalOptions.filter(function(d) {
          return this.selected;
        });
        if (s.nodes().length >= 2) {
          signalOptions.filter(function() {
              return !this.selected
            })
            .property('disabled', true);
        } else {
          signalOptions.property('disabled', false);
        }
      });

    d3.select('#someButton')
      .on('click', function(d) {
        var v = signalOptions.filter(function(d) {
          return this.selected;
        }).data();
        alert(v);
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**FOR COMMENTS**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="signal_container"></div>
  <br/>
  <button id="someButton">Get Values!</button>
  <script>
    var signal = d3.select('#signal_container');
    var signalName = ["Please Select", "Temperature", "Pressure", "Load"];
    var signalSelect = signal
      .append('select')
      .attr('class', 'select')
      .attr('multiple', '')
      .on('change', function(d) {
        var s = signalOptions.filter(function(d) {
          return this.selected;
        });
        if (s.nodes().length >= 2) {
          signalOptions.filter(function() {
              return !this.selected
            })
            .property('disabled', true);
        } else {
          signalOptions.property('disabled', false);
        }
      });

    var selectedValues = [];
    var signalOptions = signalSelect
      .selectAll('option')
      .data(signalName).enter()
      .append('option')
      .text(function(d) {
        return d;
      });

    d3.select('#someButton')
      .on('click', function(d) {
        var v = signalOptions.filter(function(d) {
          return this.selected;
        }).data();
        alert(v);
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: This code doesn’t appear to work in IE. I’ve had a play around with it and it seems as though the .on(‘click’, ) isn’t being fired up. I was wondering if you had any suggestions?

Comment: @LM2016, my bad, IE doesn't handle [click events on options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3341751/16363).  See edits above, just change the event to be on the `select`.

Comment: I thought that might be the issue so I tried it earlier but it still didn't work.

Comment: @LM2016, tested my above code snippet (the 2nd one) with IE11 (11.413.15063.0).  It seems to work fine.  If you are targeting IE<11, I don't have anyway to test that.

Comment: Thanks for your help...turns out it was a silly typo on my part.